# Jquery function does not work on Opera next but works on Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, opera

I'm having trouble with a function that basically load content into a div. It's working seamlessly in Chrome and IE, but not in Opera Next. I did some googling in vain.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function swapContent(cv1, cv2, url, id) { alert('called');
$(id).html('<img style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -80px; margin-top: -80px;" src="loading.svg" width="100px" height="100px">').show();
$.post(url, {postvariable1: cv1, postvariable2: cv2} ,function(data) {
$(id).html(data).show();
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: None, nothing on the console.

Comment: Looks like its not supported in Opera 12 http://forums.opera.com/discussion/comment/15216932#Comment_15216932

Comment: Thank buddy, any alternatives!! I really need this to work yet I'm not JQuery/Javascipt savvy